# Angular JWT and user info storage after login

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, local-storage, jwt

How good practise is saving any other user info except JWT in localstorage or cookie after successfull login? (User profile object is already saved and encrypted in jwt payload sub part.) I need user profile object ready before initializing anything else in angular (for fetching user role, login status etc.).

If I save only JWT on client side i need one extra ajax request before app load to get user info from JWT decode on server side, because token secret is on server (only after full page refresh). Token is valid or invalid, so handling errors in this case is much easier.

If I save JWT and user profile object as a string in storage on client side then this is rendundant and user can change manually that object and app can go down.

I prefer saving only JWT in storage on client side after successfully login, but i need some advice, how organize code in that case? How fetch user profile object after full page refresh?

Please help.

Comment: JWT allows you to have claims in both the header and the payload of the token. In addition to that, JWT allows you to cipher the payload while the header is signed. That way you can put information that client application (here angular in browser) can read inside the token while keeping some other information secret and available to the server only.

Answer (score 2):

The most secure solution is to store the JWT in an HTTPS-Only cookie, then make a request of the server to get the user object.

If you want to avoid that extra call to the server you will need to get creative.  One approach I'm trying is storing the claims body of the JWT on the client - just the body, the signature is excluded.  With the signature excluded the "token" is no longer a JWT and cannot be used for authentication, thus preventing the actual access token from being stolen out of local storage.

However this DOES assume two things about the claims body:

1) That the information is opaque and does not contain personally identifiable information (PII) about the user (local storage is vulnerable to XSS attacks).

2) Your Angular application does not leak sensitive information to the user if this object is modified in local storage (you should not store sensitive information in your Angular application, it should be protected by an API)

3) As with all cookie-based authentication strategies, you are protecting yourself against [CSRF Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

I work at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com) and I recently wrote a blog post on this very subject: [Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I would store just JWT and implement an extra ajax call to fetch the user profile.

But if you absolutely want to avoid this one call, you may consider using asymmetrically signed JWT instead of encrypted JWT and then extract data on the client side, assuming you control the creation of JWT.